# Using async await in Cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, cypress

I'm very new in Cypress and I'm trying to take a value from an element to use after in the test, but I can't manage to get the value. Someone said that I need to use async await, but it is not working or maybe I'm doing something wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
it.only('should access Time Worked section and insert same Staff Complement value, but negative as Flexitime',  function () {
        let timeValue = 0;
        cy.get('[data-tag="staff-complement-input"] > div > span').invoke('text').then(text => +text).then(($val) => {
            // $val = 420
            timeValue = $val;
            cy.log(timeValue) //420
        })
        cy.log(timeValue) // 0
        // need timeValue to be 420
 })
```

Comment: Cypress does _not_ expose promises, although the "thenable" interface might make it look like it does, so you can't `await` the value. Read e.g. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aliases and save the value and use it later.

```js
cy.get('[data-tag="staff-complement-input"] > div > span')
  .invoke("text")
  .then((text) => +text)
  .as("someNum")

cy.get("@someNum").then((someNum) => {
  cy.log(someNum) //420
})
```

One point to remember is that cypress clears aliases after every test. So the above will only work if you are doing everything under one `it()` block.